# I want to do registration of my app at the time of installation?

Tags: android, android-layout

Problems

1. The activity which will do registration will be shown only once
2. After registration the control should move to
   next main activity

I have used following code

Below code will not meet my requirement?

Any Help will be appreciated!!

Code in Registration Activity

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("registration", true);
    editor.commit();
```

Code in Main Activity

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean regComplete =prefs.getBoolean("registration", false);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor =prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("registration", false);

    editor.commit();

    if(regComplete)
    {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, SecureXActivity.class));
    } else 
    {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));

   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your Registration code in `SecureXActivity.class`

and Check for the Registration before `setContentView()`, if its not done then start `LoginActivity`.class

And in `LoginActivity.class` after registration complete put these code,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("registration", true);
editor.commit();
```

If you use this approach then I think you don't need `Main Activity class`..

And keep in mind this all thing done at time of your application's first run not at the time of installation.

Comment: This should work. The main problem (in the original code of OP) is that in Main Activity, the place where the program starts (every run), registration is set to false. Every time again. This way, your user will have to register everytime the program is rerun.

Comment: @Jochem - In code of OP. OP starting a `LoginActivity` if registration is not done, And the code of registration is in `RegistrationActivity`.

Comment: Yeah but there is also code that changes the preference in MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

The Registration Activity should be like this:

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends Activity {

    public static SharedPreferences pref;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                        boolean regComplete =prefs.getBoolean("registration", false);
                        if(regComplete){
                        //go to main class
                        }else{
                        //stay in the registration class
                        }
}
}
```

and the Main class should be:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    RegistrationActivity.pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putBoolean("registration", true);
        // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();
}
}
```